# NextJS form to send data to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, forms, next.js

I'm new to JavaScript, know the basics and lack experience, but I want to learn more.
I created a project using NextJS, which is a light framework that works with ReactJS, and what I am struggling to understand is how can I create a simple form, with one field where you enter data and once clicked on submit, the data to be sent over to a MongoDB collection.

I managed to connect the project to a MongoDB database and by accessing a page to make it return some data from a collection, but I'm trying to understand the structure of how can I do this, to send the data to a collection.

Do I have to somehow make one js file to reference another js file where I have the MongoDB configuration and make use of the connectToDatabase function and send the submit data via a simple insertOne query within the js file? Or do I have to send the data to another js file where I have some sort of API configuration and do a POST?

If you could advise on how can I achieve this, it would be much appreciated. Even with an article or anything that could help me better understand the structure behind.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved.
I figured it out on my own by analysing this official NextJS example with mongoose built within: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mongodb-mongoose

I did it with 3 files: one for the front-end where to input the data, one for the API call that inserts the data in the database, one for the database schema.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I didn't even think to checkout their gitHub repo. Doing this using the design pattern you mentioned worked for me as well.